# Do I win memory by explicitly disposing imageView.Image?

Tags: memory-management, xamarin.ios, garbage-collection, dispose, nsautoreleasepool

I have this code in my app:

```
var newImage = // ...

if (imageView.Image != null && imageView.Image != newImage)
    imageView.Image.Dispose ();

imageView.Image = newImage;
```

I have three related questions:

- Does it immediately release the memory occupied by the previous `imageView.Image`?
- If it does, is there a cleaner solution?
- Does this have anything to do with `NSAutoreleasePool`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does it immediately release the memory occupied by the previous imageView.Image?

**Not immediately** but it should be much faster than waiting for the Garbage Collector.

Calling `Dispose` will drop the *managed* reference to the *native* `UIImage`. If nothing else (natively) has a reference to the `UIImage` (RetainCount == 0) then it will be freed (ObjC reference counting).

In your code `imageView` still has a reference to it until its `Image` property is set to `newImage` - which is why I answered **not immediately**.

> If it does, is there a cleaner solution?

Not really. Letting the GC do it's work is cleaner looking - but image can be very big and are worth freeing asap.

Also it's not really worth (and would not be cleaner anyway) adding a local variable to make sure (if no other native reference exists) the image will be freed immediately - it will happen on the next line.

> Does this have anything to do with NSAutoreleasePool?

Anything ? well it's memory related in both cases.

Creating images will use (cache) the current `NSAutoreleasePool` and will, eventually, be drained. If you process a lot of stuff (e.g. a loop) then it's often worth having your own, short-lived, pool to ensure a faster drain.

Some API (well know to require a lot of memory) are decorated with an attribute that will automatically add (btouch) an `NSAutoreleasePool` - but it's not easy to find out which.

In doubt you better use Apple Instruments to measure...

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, this is more or less what I expected. Regarding `NSAutoreleasePool`, I was hoping that maybe if I wrap assignment in a dedicated pool, I wouldn't have to write this `if` condition. I guess this isn't the case? I'm afraid I don't understand how `NSAutoreleasePool` should be used in MonoTouch, what draining is, and how it plays with Mono's GC.

Comment: `NSAutoreleasePool` is like ObjC (Apple documentation applies) and it's **not** directly related to the GC (which only cover managed references) since it's a **native** reference will be kept in the pool. That also means it does not *solve* using the `if` and calling `Dispose`. See Rolf's answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/10440506/220643 for an example where it *was* needed but any, previously, existing `UIImage` assigned to the `UIImageView.Image` won't be disposed (in that example) until the GC process it (so it would be better to call `Dispose` on it, if not null, like your own example).